# Conversion from Func<object,string> to Func<string,string> works but to Func<int,string> fails

Tags: c#, generics, covariance, func, contravariance

I have the following code:

```
static Func<object, string> s_objToString = (x) => x.ToString();
static Func<string, string> s_stringToString = s_objToString; //compiles
static Func<int, string> s_intToString = s_objToString; //error
```

The second line compiles but the third line fails to compile with error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type '`System.Func<object,string>`' to '`System.Func<int,string>`'

**Why is that?**

I understand that with genetics although string is derived from object a `List<string>` does not derive from `List<object>`, but here `object` to `string` works and `object` to `int` fails, why?

OK let's say I understood why; the question now is there a way around it (other then defining `MyInt` class to box `int` because `Func<object,string>` to `Func<MyInt,string>` works)?

Comment: It's always worth checking the preview for a question, especially when you're asking questions about generics (or anything else that uses `<>` angle brackets), to make sure that your text is showing up or mark it up accordingly.

Comment: @Roey You can box an `int` just by casting it to `object`, (or passing it to `s_objToString`!), you don't need a new class to do that.

Comment: passing it to `s_objToString` or casting it to object might work on a simple solution. but my issue is with functions like: `public static string codeList<T>(List<T> thelist, Func<T, string> coder)`  for details see [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13026128/implemting-genetics-in-a-function-using-func)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because `Func` is defined as  `Func<in T, out TResult>`, MSDN is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx), so `T` is *contra-variant* with `in` keyword, that is, you can use either the type you specified or any type that is less derived, but remember that *co-variance and contra-variance* do not support for *value type*:

[Why covariance and contravariance do not support value type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12454794/why-covariance-and-contravariance-do-not-support-value-type)

So, it works for `string` but does not work out with `int`. You might need to read more about *covariance and contravariance*:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233060.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx

Comment: Ok, thanks. Is there a way around it? other then defining MyInt class to box int cause Func<object,string> to Func<MyInt,string> work

Comment: @RoeyNissim: What I would say, you should consider your design to avoid this case. Btw, you should post another question instead of update question in here to ask another problem

Answer (score 3):

Because co/contra-variance doesn't work for value types.

Please take a look [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx)

Variance is supported only if a type parameter is a reference type. Variance is not supported for value types. 
The following doesn’t compile either:

```
// int is a value type, so the code doesn't compile.
IEnumerable<Object> objects = new List<int>(); // Compiler error here.
```

Comment: irreverent, the following does not compile with string either static List<object> objs = new List<string>();

Comment: @RoeyNissim: concept covariance and contra-variance just works with generic interface and delegate, so List is invariant, not covariant

Comment: @RoeyNissim @CuongLe: This answer is correct, though bad example `List<int>` here. The compile error in the answer results from invalid cast from `IEnumerable<int>` to `IEnumerable<object>` per-se.

Comment: @DannyChen: yes, it's correct, I just tried to explain for @RoeyNissim why the `List<object> objs = new List<string>()` does not work