# Implementing generics in a function using Func

Tags: c#, generics, func

I have a follow static function:

```
public static string codeList<T>(List<T> thelist, Func<T, string> coder);
```

using this function with my own objects is not problem for example:

```
string code = codeList<MyClass>(myclassList, MyClass.code);
```

Where MyClass.code is a static function (defined in MyClass) that gets MyClass and returns string.

The problem is when I try to use this function with `List<int>` or `List<double>` what I do now is predefining statics like `Func<int,string> intCoder = (x) => x.ToString();` and `Func<double,string> (x) => x.ToString();` and use them.
Is there another way of doing that? something like:

```
string code = codeList<int>(intList, Int32.ToString);
```

Comment: @sll: I changed it, it's seems most reasonable that it's about generics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with

```
string code = codeList<int>(intList, Convert.ToString);
```

It just so happens that [`Convert.ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tostring.aspx) has [an overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x70d7t0y.aspx) with the appropriate signature.

The problem with [`int.ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3k9ccxf6.aspx) is that none of its overloads have the appropriate signature (they don't take an `int` parameter as it is implied). In that case there would be nothing you could do apart from defining an adapter function.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to declare a variable for the func. You can just put the lambda expression as the parameter value

```
string code = codeList(intList, i => i.ToString());
```

Comment: Again Amiram this is not the issue, I don't want to create a new function (and yes calling i => i.ToString() creates a new function) my assumption was that a rich language such as C# would have this kind of functions and its seem that I was correct to assume since Convert.ToString does it.

Comment: This is creating a new function but it gives you more flexibility. With this way you can use any of the overrides that Int32.ToString has. You can't do it with passing only reference to `Convert.ToString()`.