# I'm unsure why this substitution is unsafe

Tags: c#, type-conversion, covariance, out, type-parameter

Consider the following:

```
class ControllerFactoryBase<P> : where P : PledgeReadOnly
{
    public void Foo()
    {
         PledgeRepositoryReadOnly<P> repos = PledgeRepository();
         new AdminController(repos); // compilation error here
    }
}

public interface PledgeRepositoryReadOnly<out P> where P : PledgeReadOnly
{
    IEnumerable<P> GetPledgesToBeneficiary();

}

public class AdminController
{
    public AdminController(PledgeRepositoryReadOnly<PledgeReadOnly> pledgeProvider)
    { ... }
}
```

I'm getting a compilation error on the instantiation of AdminController with message:

```
cannot convert from 'PledgeRepositoryReadOnly<P>' to 'PledgeRepositoryReadOnly<PledgeReadOnly>'
```

and I'm not sure why.  I believe this substitution is safe.  Can you help me understand why it is not?

**edit** more digestible presentation: http://csharppad.com/gist/9283391

Comment: @chenZ - replacing 'out' with 'in' causes a compilation error on PledgeRepositoryReadOnly.

Comment: yes,i try your code,it can compile,no error

Comment: can you paste PledgeRepository() ?

Comment: @chenZ That method is actually abstract, but sure ' protected abstract PledgeRepository<P,Guid,Guid> PledgeRepository();'  I argue this is irrelevant though because there is no error on the repos assignment line.

Comment: is PledgeRepository like 'class PledgeRepository<P, T1, T2> : PledgeRepositoryReadOnly<P> where P : PledgeReadOnly',i use this,and everything is ok

Comment: @chenZ almost.  I've uploaded the code in a more digestible format at: csharppad.com/gist/9283391

Comment: @chenZ does the code I provided in the csharpapd link compile for you?  If so, what version of csc are you using?

Comment: i got a same err with your code,if PledgeReadOnly is a class,that's ok.interface,err.

Comment: or,change all where P:PledgeReadOnly to where P:class,PledgeReadOnly

Comment: Relevant thread:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12454794/why-covariance-and-contravariance-do-not-support-value-type

Answer (score 1):

with some step,finaly,i get what's wrong
first

```
public interface PledgeReadOnly
{

}
```

this is a interface,and

```
where P : PledgeReadOnly
```

it mean p must be a PledgeReadOnly
but

```
public struct x : PledgeReadOnly
{
}

public class y : PledgeReadOnly
{
}
```

both class and struct and implement from a interface
not sure P is a class or a struct
you can change your PledgeReadOnly from interface to class
or you can change all

```
where P : PledgeReadOnly
```

to

```
where P : class,PledgeReadOnly
```

it make sure P is a class

Comment: Interesting.  Why does that matter?