# Is it possible to create a delegate for *any* Action<T>?

Tags: c#, events, parameters, delegates, action

I'm trying to figure out why this doesn't work:

```
public void DefaultAction( object obj = null ){}

public void Start()
{
    SomeReferenceType obj;
    DefaultAction( obj ); //works

    int i;
    string s;
    DefaultAction( i ); //works
    DefaultAction( s ); //works
}

//however...

public event Action OnNullAction = DefaultAction; //works
public event Action<SomeReferenceType> OnObjectAction = DefaultAction; //works
public event Action<int> OnIntAction = DefaultAction; //doesn't work!!
```

Trying to bind a `void(object)` to an `Action<ValueType>` throws a parameter mismatch error, even though you can call the function directly with an int/string/bool what have you. Is there some mysterious boxing/unboxing happening? And regardless, is it possible to create a delegate that can respond to any `Action<T>`?

Comment: It's not mysterious that an `int` would have to be boxed to pass to an `Action<object>`.

Comment: This is a limitation of generic contravariance, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12454794/why-covariance-and-contravariance-do-not-support-value-type

Comment: `public event Action OnNullAction = DefaultAction` this can't work.

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate, but see my answer below for more details, in case the concepts of covariance and contravariance are unclear to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make it generic

```
public void DefaultAction<T>(T param) { }
```

Comment: Thanks for this! This does exactly what I need it to.

Answer (score 7):

You have discovered that *delegate contravariance requires reference types*.

That's pretty highfalutin, I know.

First off, let me clearly state what covariance and contravariance are.  Suppose you have a relationship between types: "A value of type `Giraffe` can be assigned to a variable of type `Animal`".  Let's notate that as

```
Animal <-- Giraffe
```

A generic type `C<T>` is said to be *covariant in `T`* if *replacing every type with `C<that type>`  preserves the direction of the arrow.*

```
IEnumerable<Animal> <-- IEnumerable<Giraffe>
```

Since C# 4.0, when I added this feature to the language, ou can use a sequence of giraffes anywhere you need a sequence of animals.

A generic type `C<T>` is said to be *contravariant in `T`* if the replacement *reverses* the direction of the arrow:

```
Action<Animal> --> Action<Giraffe>
```

If you need an action that requires that you give it a `Giraffe` and you have an action that can take any `Animal`, then you're all set; you need something that can take a `Giraffe` and an `Action<Animal>` can take a `Giraffe`. But this is not *covariant*. If you have an `Action<Giraffe>` in hand and you need an `Action<Animal>`, you can't use the `Action<Giraffe>` because *you can pass a `Tiger` to an `Action<Animal>` but not an `Action<Giraffe>`.

What about `Func<T>`?  It is *covariant in `T`*. If you need a function that returns an `Animal` and you have a function that returns a `Giraffe`, you're good, because the `Giraffe` will be an `Animal`.

What about `Func<A, R>`?  It is *contravariant in `A` and covariant in `R`*. It should be clear why.

So now that we know what covariance and contravariance of generic types are, what are the rules in C#? The rules are:

- The type declarations must be annotated with `in` (contravariant) and `out` (covariant). For example, `delegate R Func<in A, out R>(A a)`.  Notice that the `in` is the thing that goes *into* the function and the `out` is the thing that comes *out* of the function; we named them `in` and `out` on purpose.
- The compiler has to be able to prove that the annotations are safe.  See the spec or my blog for details.
- Variance is only supported on *generic delegates and interfaces*, not on generic structs, enums or classes.
- The varying types have to both be reference types.

So now we come to your question. Why do they have to both be reference types?  You deduced the answer: **where is the boxing instruction?**

```
Action<object> oa = (object x)=>whatever;
Action<int> ia = oa; // Suppose this works.
ia(123);
```

Where is the boxing instruction?  Not in the body of the lambda assigned to `oa` -- that thing takes an `object` already.  Not in the call to `ia(123)` -- that thing takes an integer.  The only possible solution is that `oa` and `ia` be *unequal*; that this be a shorthand for

```
Action<object> oa = (object x)=>{whatever};
Action<int> ia = (int x)=>{ oa(x); };
```

But if that's what you meant to say, then just say that.  People expect that a reference conversion will maintain referential identity, so C# outlaws covariant or contravariant conversions that would have to box or unbox a value.

If you have more questions on this, search my old blog (blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert) for `covariance` or search for the C# covariance FAQ.

Comment: Question is "Is it possible to create a delegate for *any* Action<T>?". It's not "Why can't I cast Action<int> to Action<object>?".

Comment: @Eric thanks for the great explanation of *why* this doesn't work. Atomosk thanks for the easy workaround :)

Comment: @Atomosk: The question as stated is *incoherent*. I can't figure out what "is it possible to create a delegate for any `Action<T>` even *means*.  `Action<T>` *is* a delegate, so the question is nonsensical. Rather than trying to address the nonsensical question I instead chose to address the other question stated: **is there some kind of boxing happening?** and the implied question **why is there a type mismatch?**, as those are actually questions that have answers.

Comment: Isn't `Func<T>` covariant in `T`?

Comment: Your answer is great. I meant duplciate question isn't actualy duplicate. I don't know how to comment "marked as duplicate by Eric Lippert", so decided to write here.