# Unable to cast object of type 'MyType' to type 'IMyInterface`1[System.IConvertible]'

Tags: c#

I have a problem with casting my implementing classes to my generic interface.
I have several internal classes inside a class that implement this interface.
Then I have a method that is supposed to return any one of these classes, but the cast it contains fails for T != String.

Sample:

```
public interface IMyInterface<out T> where T : IConvertible
{/*Contents*/}

internal class MyStringClass : IMyInterface<String>  {/*Contents*/}
internal class MySingleClass : IMyInterface<Single>  {/*Contents*/}

IMyInterface<IConvertible> CreateMyObject(Type type)
{
    return (IMyInterface<IConvertible>)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
}
```

Seeing as String is a reference type, while the others are structs, is this related? There must be something I'm missing here. (Possibly related as well: If I remove the covariance of T, casting MyStringClass fails as well.)

I don't usually work with C# so this is a bit unfamiliar to me. Any explanation of why this doesn't work, as well as any pointer towards a solution is welcome.

EDIT: My internal classes that implement IMyInterface are passed as `type` (typeof)

EDIT2: As Alireza explained in an answer further down, making T covariant makes it not support value, types, which explains why `T = String` works, but not `T = ValueType`. I'm still stuck as to how I can make this work though...

Comment: What is passed as `type`?

Comment: @pwas: Updated the question. It's my classes that implement the interface.

Comment: `var stringThingy = CreateMyObject(typeof(MyStringClass))` works for me at least. No exception, and argument is not null.

Comment: @Caramiriel, in question "cast it contains fails for T != String."

Comment: This answer of same question is very useful http://stackoverflow.com/a/12454932/2392330

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That `out` modifier you put in front of T made it covariant, but from [MSDN document for `out`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx):

> Covariance and contravariance are supported for reference types, but they are not supported for value types.

UPDATE: Sometimes (if your design allows it and you don't need the non-generic stuff outside the class) you can use a non-generic interface to solve the problem:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{ /*non-generic content*/}

public interface IMyInterface<out T> : IMyInterface where T : IConvertible
{/*Contents*/}

internal class MyStringClass : IMyInterface<String> {/*Contents*/}
internal class MySingleClass : IMyInterface<Single> {/*Contents*/}

static IMyInterface CreateMyObject(Type type)
{
    return (IMyInterface)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize that. However, if I remove the covariance, casting `MyStringClass` to the interface doesn't work anymore either, and that still leaves the question of why the cast doesn't work in the first place.

Comment: It is because unlike `array`s generic types of compatible types are not compatible themselves. I mean a `string[]` can be assigned to an `IConvertible[]` but `IMyInterface<String>` and `IMyInterface<IConvertible>` are totally different types.

Comment: the `out` modifier just makes that assignment of course with some limitations possible for reference types.

Comment: I see. I guess this answers my question of why it doesn't work. Going to mark answer as accepted because it answered the question, but if you (or anyone else) have a solution for how to make it work, it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: @user3839796 A `String` (reference type) is an `IConvertible` through a ***reference conversion***. Therefore the covariance of `IMyInterface<out T>` applies, and an `IMyInterface<String>` is an `IMyInterface<IConvertible>`. On the other hand, a `Single` (value type, a.k.a. `float`) is an `IConvertible` through a ***boxing conversion***, and as stated in the answer here, covariance does not apply in that case. So yes, it is because it is a value type (`struct`).

Comment: According to your design, sometimes you can define a non-generic interface `IMyInterface` as a parent for `IMyInterface<T>` then put anything non-generic inside this interface and specify that type as your return value

Comment: I want to access a method with a generic return parameter, but what you suggest might possibly work with some workarounds. It's at least way closer to a solution than I was previously.