# Why can't I use covariance with two generic type parameters?

Tags: c#, generics, covariance

Consider the following example:

```
class Base {}

class Derived : Base {}

class Test1
{
    private List<Derived> m_X;

    public IEnumerable<Base> GetEnumerable()
    {
        return m_X;
    }
}
```

This compiles just fine, because `IEnumerable<T>` is **covariant** in `T`.

However, if I do exactly the same thing but now with generics:

```
class Test2<TBase, TDerived> where TDerived : TBase
{
    private List<TDerived> m_X;

    public IEnumerable<TBase> GetEnumerable()
    {
        return m_X;
    }
}
```

I get the compiler error

> Cannot convert expression type
>   'System.Collection.Generic.List' to return type
>   'System.Collection.Generic.IEnumerable'

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I suppose there must be an explanation, however, using `return m_X.Cast<TBase>();` will solve your case.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thing is, in the first case, the `Base` is known to be a class. In the second case, the type parameter `T` could be either class or a struct (this is how compiler thinks).

Solve the case by specifying that `T` is a class, and the error will disappear:

```
class Test2<TBase, TDerived> where TDerived : class, TBase
{
    private List<TDerived> m_X;

    public IEnumerable<TBase> GetEnumerable()
    {
        return m_X;
    }
}
```

So, the compiler tries to show us that TDerived could be a struct (since you didn't specify `class` constraint) and [as we](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12454794/why-covariance-and-contravariance-do-not-support-value-type) [already know](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx#InterfaceCovariantTypeParameters), **covariance and contravariance do not work with structs**.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance as I'm still fairly new to C# (or maybe this is one of those really abstruse things about .NET in general), but doesn't the fact that `TDerived` derives from `TBase` -- which is a class -- preclude the ambiguity regarding whether `TDerived` is, itself, a class or a struct?  Can you derive a struct from a class?

Comment: Interesting! I tried `where TBase : class` but that had no effect.

Comment: @roryap In C# yes, but not necessarily in the CLR. `ValueType` is a class, but all structs derive from it.

Comment: @roryap no, you can't derive a struct, or from a struct.

Comment: @AgentFire -- So why do you need to be explicit, e.g. `where TDerived : class, TBase` vs. `where TDerived : TBase` since `TBase` is a class.?

Comment: @roryap because you **can declare** a type parameter with a struct type, like int: `void Foo<T>() where T : int`.

Comment: @roryap `TBase` could be *any* type. The fact that it maps to the class `Base` is coincidence. The compiler doesn't know that detail.

Comment: @CoderDennis -- Okay, but are we all in agreement that the compiler *could* (and maybe *should*) know?

Comment: @roryap Go read the blog post "[Minus 100 points](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2004/01/12/57985.aspx)" by Eric Gunnerson (a member of the C# compiler team). It explains pretty well why features like you describe may have not made it in to the program.

Comment: @roryap without the `class` constraint, `new Test2<int, int>()` would be valid. The compiler has no way of knowing you won't do that unless you add the class constraint to `TDerived`. Simply specifying `where TDerived : TBase` doesn't ensure that `TBase` or `TDerived` are classes.

Comment: @roryap What you're talking about is a C# rule. In CIL, this rule doesn't apply (all C# structs derive from a class). When a project is built, it's not C# anymore, it's CIL. But you can still use that code (for example, those generic types) from a C# project. Thus, I'm guessing the C# compiler simply doesn't assume that its own rules are also enforced implicitly by all possible CLI languages. So, instead, it requires an explicit constraint.

Comment: This had me stumped, even though I had just explained why one had to use `default(T)` instead of `null` for a generic type.  Thanks!