# Why doesn't overload resolution work here?

Tags: c#, generics, covariance, type-inference, overloading

Consider this snippet:

```
var bytes = new byte[] {0, 0, 0, 0};
bytes.ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

This will result in the compile time error:

```
No overload for 'System.Console.WriteLine(int)' matches delegate 'System.Action<byte>'
```

You can declare a lamdba as a workaround, `bytes.ToList().ForEach((b => Console.WriteLine(b)))`, but why doesn't overload resolution work in the first case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Foreach method will be inferred as `Foreach(Action<byte> action)`.

There is no `WriteLine` overload which takes a single parameter `byte` and thus it doesn't compile.

> What's up with that? Why can't it compile with
>   `Console.WriteLine(int)`?

Because `Action<int>` isn't compatible to `Action<byte>`

From C# language specification

**15.2 Delegate compatibility:**

A method or delegate M is compatible with a delegate type D if all of the following are true:

- D and M have the same number of parameters, and each parameter in D has the same ref or out modifiers as the corresponding parameter in M.
- For each value parameter (a parameter with no ref or out modifier), **an identity conversion (§6.1.1) or implicit reference conversion (§6.1.6) exists** from the parameter type in D to the corresponding parameter type in M.
- For each ref or out parameter, the parameter type in D is the same as the parameter type in M.
- An identity or implicit reference conversion exists from the return type of M to the return type of D.

Overload resolution fails at an [identity conversion (§6.1.1)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691281%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) or [implicit reference conversion (§6.1.6)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691284%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) exist; None of them exist here. Byte doesn't have identity conversion to int or implicit reference conversion either. So, it can't compile to `Console.WriteLine(int)`.

> Why can't it compile with `Console.WriteLine(int)`?

Because `Action<T>` is contravariant on type parameter T and [contravariance doesn't work for value types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12454794/why-covariance-and-contravariance-do-not-support-value-type). If it were some other reference type, it would have compiled to `Console.WriteLine(object)` because contravariance do work with reference type.

For example:

```
Action<int> action1 = Console.WriteLine;//Compiles to Console.WriteLine(int)
Action<byte> action2 = Console.WriteLine;//Won't compile
Action<StringBuilder> action3 = Console.WriteLine;//Compiles to Console.WriteLine(object)
```

As you can see `Action<StringBuilder>` does compile even though there is no overload of `Console.WriteLine(StringBuilder)`; It is because reference types supports contravariance.

Comment: I'm not sure I see the relation between covariance/contravariance and implicit conversions. There is no inheritance between `int` and `byte`.

Comment: @Kobi I don't get it. `ForEach` takes a `Action<T>`; Implicit conversion doesn't apply there. It is contravariance which is relevant here.

Comment: @Kobi, In this case, the type of the `Action`s won't match because of `int`and `byte` not being inherited in one way or the other.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I just tried with an interface `IFoo` and `struct Foo : IFoo` and I could not assign a method `void Foo(IFoo f)` to an `Action<Foo>` with the same compile time error - good call for sure :)

Comment: When you call `Console.WriteLine((byte)2)` you really call `Console.WriteLine(int)`. That is because there is an implicit operator converting `byte` to `int`, not because `byte` extends (inherits) `int`. So, I don't understand how covariance has anything to do with this issue, unless you're trying to explain why `Console.WriteLine(object)` isn't called.

Comment: @Kobi That's a different story. You're talking about calling the method not method group conversion. Implicit delegate conversion doesn't care whether you have implicit conversion or not.

Comment: @Kobi "unless you're trying to explain why Console.WriteLine(object) isn't called" I already explained you **value types doesn't support contravariance**. `byte` is a value type so it doesn't call `Console.WriteLine(object)`.

Comment: @Sriram - I know you explained that, that's exactly what I said `:)`, but you didn't explain why `Console.WriteLine(int)` isn't called (but that's just a feature C# doesn't have).

Comment: @SriramSakthivel So ultimately, my code doesn't compile because overload resolution (or rather, implicit conversion) functioned, but `Action<byte>` is not an `Action<int>`? Or have I missed the boat here?

Comment: @Kobi I guess I understand your question. Updated my answer. See if that makes sense :)

Comment: @jdphenix I've updated my answer with c# specs. In short `Action<int>` is not compatible with `Action<byte>` and thus it doesn't compile.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Good deal, thanks. A little bit to wrap my head around for sure but your explanation helped. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Simply put, the signatures don't match as there is no overload for `Console.WriteLine(byte)`.

The lambda example works because you are providing a method that expects a `byte` which satisfies the signature, and then subsequently passing it into `Console.WriteLine` (which will implicitly handle `byte`).

Comment: When I call `Console.WriteLine()` with a `byte`, there is an implicit conversion to `int` so `Console.WriteLine(int)` is called. So what about lambdas makes this implicit conversion not work here? I'm sorry to change up the question on you but I think it's a better statement of my misunderstanding.

Comment: @jdphenix what makes you think it performs an implicit conversion to int? I think it's more likely that ToString is being called on the byte. The problem is the compiler sees Console.WriteLine(int) but is looking to pass a byte, it has no idea that the target method is capable of implicitly handling that type, it just sees a type mismatch.

Comment: I checked the IL emitted, `    IL_0004:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)` when passed a byte