# converting primitive or non primitive dynamically to list

Tags: c#

I have an object that could be any type. I have a check to see if its an array and then I need to convert it to a `List<object>` if it is. I am having trouble handling the case where its a primitive array as shown below. It is not an `IEnumerable<object>` in this case. Note I cannot use LINQ in this framework:

```
object value = SomeFunction();
if( value.GetType().IsArray )
{
  try
  {
     List<object> l = new List<object>( (IEnumerable<object>)value );
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
    //here its failing because its no an object
  }
}
```

`

Comment: Why do you not iterate it and add it to the list in that case?

Comment: Is the array known to be single dimensional, or might it be multi-dimensional?

Comment: single dimension. I can itterate it, but since i don't know the type i can't use enumerable like above. The only idea i could come up with was reflection using the get method and count. Seems slow though.

Comment: Note that your question would be more accurate if you use "value type" instead of "primitive type".  You can't convert arrays of `struct`s or `decimal`s to `IEnumerable<object>` either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't cast to IEnumerable directly because [covariance doesn't work for value types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12454794/why-covariance-and-contravariance-do-not-support-value-type).  The Linq answer would be to call `Cast` to cast each element of the underlying array to an `object` (boxing them in the process).

I'm not sure what you mean by "I can't use Linq", but you could replicate what Linq's `Cast` would do:

```
object value = SomeFunction();
if( value.GetType().IsArray )
{
  try
  {
     List<object> l = new List<object>();
     foreach(object o in (IEnumerable)value) // implicitly cast each item to object
     {
        l.Add(o);
     }
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
    //here its failing because its no an object
  }
}
```

If you want to use covariance for reference types you can check the underlying type of the array at runtime:

```
List<object> l = new List<object>();
if(value.GetType().GetElementType().IsValueType)
{
    foreach(object o in (IEnumerable)value)
    {
        l.Add(o);
    }
}
else
{
    l.AddRange((IEnumerable<object>)value);
}
```