# Is int (Int32) considered an object in .NET or a primitive (not int?)?

Tags: c#, .net, int, primitive, value-type

Is int (aka `Int32`) an object , or a primitive in .NET (I'm not asking regarding `int?`)?

I hit F12 on the saved word `int` and got :

```
public struct Int32 : IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible, IComparable<int>, IEquatable<int>

{ ... }
```

It doesn't inherit from Object , does it mean that `int` is a primitive ?

Comment: Its a struct, which is not allowed to specify a base type. The base type of `System.ValueType` is implied by the `struct` keyword. In other languages (e.g. Java) there is a distinction between objects and primitives, however in .NET the type system is unified. All non-pointer, non-interface types inherit from `System.Object`.

Comment: Do you mean is Int32 "a data type provided by a programming language as a basic building block"? [primative](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/primitive/info)

Comment: Wondering why it doesn't show Int32 inheriting Object since it does

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Everything in C# inherits from `object`, including `int`.

From [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.aspx):

> Int32 is an immutable value type that represents signed integers

[and](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Both reference and value types are derived from the ultimate base
>   class Object.

Comment: This is not correct. `int` does not inherit from `object`. Assigning an `int` value to an `object` variable is called boxing.

Comment: @YacoubMassad: Well, [MSDN on `System.Object`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says "All classes, structures, enumerations, and delegates" inherit from `System.Object`. [`System.Int32`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a structure. Draw conclusions for yourself.

Comment: @YacoubMassad It does inherit from `object` - how would it override `Equals`, `GetHashCode` etc. otherwise? Boxing is related to representation, not inheritance.

Comment: `(1 is object)` returns true. So I guess you guys are right.

Comment: Well , tried this one and it was enough : `int xx = 1;
            if (xx is object)
            {
                Console.Write("yeap");
            }`

Comment: It's not as clear-cut as this answer makes out. You can assign an `int` to an `object` (`object a = 12;`) using boxing, however you [cannot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12454794/why-covariance-and-contravariance-do-not-support-value-type) treat an `int` or other struct in the covariant position of an interface as an object (`IEnumerable<object> b = Enumerable.Repeat(5,1);` fails). So in that sense it does not always behave like an object.

Answer (score 4):

`Int32` is a struct, which is like a type (compile time) and not an object (run time). So you can't say "`Int32` is an object", but you could say "`Int32` inherits from object".

A struct is a [ValueType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype.aspx) and a ValueType derives from object.

`int` and `Int32` and synonyms where `Int32` is better suited in operations where the reader cares about the length in bits (bit fiddling operations, overflow situations etc.)

Answer (score 3):

Referring to [this MSDN site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya5y69ds.aspx) there are 15 build in types, from which 2 are classes (object and string) and the rest are primitives:

```
bool - System.Boolean
byte - System.Byte
sbyte - System.SByte
char - System.Char
decimal - System.Decimal
double - System.Double
float - System.Single
int - System.Int32
uint - System.UInt32
long - System.Int64
ulong - System.UInt64
object - System.Object
short - System.Int16
ushort - System.UInt16
string - System.String
```

Comment: These types are built into *C#*, which is not necessarily the same as being built into *.NET* as a whole. Also, note that the linked page mentions "simple types", which is a C# thing that may or may not be meant to be the same as a "primitive type". [`Type.IsPrimitive`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isprimitive%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) provides a somewhat different list of types that are considered to be primitive types for the .NET Framework as a whole.

Comment: There are no primitives in C#, you can call `GetType`  on any `int` literal, and `GetType` is declared in `System.Object`

Comment: Try this code : `int xx = 1;
            if (xx is object)
            {
                Console.Write("yeap");
            }`

Comment: You should maybe consider a difference between how are primitives implemented in C# and Java. Java pretends to be fully objective language, and have type `Integer`, `Double` and so deriving from base object type. However these are reference types and are not the same as primitive `int`, `double` and so, and are *not* interchangable.

In C# you always cast any primitive type to `object` or to it's nullable counterpart. This is due to superior boxing/unboxing features.

Primitive types in C# are value types, and are stored on the stack as-is.

Answer (score 1):

The primitive types are the one identified through keywords, so yes **int** is a primitive type.

The primitive types also allow you to use that as literals.

However, the underlying type that the keyword identifies is **System.Int32** which is not a primitive types.
This is a value type, not a reference type (or object).

Comment: I find this definition questionable as it lacks scope for the term "primitive types". Primitive types of what? The .NET Framework? Then, this definition cannot be correct, as different .NET languages can have different sets of keywords. A language? Then I wonder whether this is what was asked about.

Comment: The definition of "Primitive type" you reference is for VB.NET.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN - "The primitive types are identified through keywords, which are aliases for predefined types in the System namespace. A primitive type is completely indistinguishable from the type it aliases: writing the reserved word int is exactly the same as writing System.Int32.
Because a primitive type aliases a regular type, every primitive type has members. For example, Integer has the members declared in System.Int32. Literals can be treated as instances of their corresponding types."

So basically **int** and **Int32** are synonymous; You would be inclined to use **int** where you just need 'an integer',where when using **Int32** the size is explicitly shown so future maintainers will know it's safe to enlarge an **int** if appropriate, but should take care changing **Int32** variables in the same way. The resulting code using both will be identical, but the difference is only in the readability of the code or also if you want to call it code presentation.

You can read Applied .NET Framework Programming - the author Jeffrey Richter makes a good example of using the full type names. Here are the main things that I remembered:

Type names can vary between .NET languages. For example, in C#, long maps to System.Int64 while in C++ with managed extensions, long maps to Int32. Since languages can be mixed-and-matched while using .NET, you can be sure that using the explicit class name will always be clearer, no matter the reader's preferred language.

Answer (score 0):

**int** in C# is an alias for **Int32**, and they behave exactly the same. One would usually use **Int32**, instead of **int**, for readability and explicitness. Now, unfortunately your question can’t really be answered with a simple *yes* or *no* answer. - **int** *implicitly* derives from the ValueType Type which itself derives from the Object Type. And so, in C#, all Types **do** in-fact derive from the Object Type.

But, since ValueType can not be *explicitly* derived from (because it is an Abstract Class), the compiler needs to , and does, inherently know that **int** *implicitly* inherits from ValueType. So **int** does derive from the Object Type, just not *explicitly*.

Though **int** is not a Reference Type, it can still be treated like one ( like a Type that derives *explicitly* from the Object Type ) through a process called *boxing*.

It is a bit confusing at first. Everywhere online, and in books, people say that with regards to C#: All Types derive from the Object Type, which *is* **true**, but in the case of certain ValueType Types they just don’t inherit *explicitly*.

Furthermore, **ints**, as well as other ValueTypes, are constructed using Structs - not Classes in the way Reference types are.