# Delegate "wrong return type"

Tags: c#, delegates

On one hand I have the following delegate :

```
public delegate IBar FooDelegate(string str);
public delegate IBar FooDelegateWithRef(string str, IBar someBar);
```

On the other hand I have a generic class :

```
public class MyBaseClass
    where T : IBar, new()
{
    public FooDelegate myFunc;
    public FooDelegateWithRef myFuncWithRef;
}

public class MyClass<T> : MyBaseClass
    where T : IBar, new()
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        myFunc = Foo; //"Wrong return type"
        myFuncWithRef = FooWithRef; //"No overload...matches delegate"
    }

    public T Foo(string){ ... }
    public T FooWithRef(string, IBar){ ... }
}
```

My problem is when I do the following :

```
FooDelegate fooRef = MyClassInstance.Foo;
```

I get a 'wrong return type' error. I understand that a delegate signature *must* match the method signature, but since the "where" instruction in the generic actually specify clearly T *is* IBar, why doesn't it work ?

So two questions in one :
 - why the compiler refuse to consider that the method signature is matching ?
 - more importantly, how can I make this work ? I would prefer a delegate-friendly solution rather than using Func for conventions reasons.

note : I tried looking around for an answer, yet I might have the wrong wording for the question, so feel free to slap me in the face If this has been answered before.

**EDIT** : As @Jonathon Chase pointed out, my sample code doesn't quite wraps the problem. A non-working example can be found [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JncI6w). Edited the code above to reflect the issue.

**EDIT 2** : All the answers where very informative to me, thanks a lot for your time. I would have checked all three if I could !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "wrong return type" error is because [variance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173174.aspx) does not [support value types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12454794/why-covariance-and-contravariance-do-not-support-value-type).  So a `class` implementing `IBar` can be converted, while a `struct` implementing won't be:

```
class RefTypeBar : IBar {}
struct ValueTypeBar : IBar {}

FooDelegate f1 = new MyClass<RefTypeBar>().Foo;  // This works
FooDelegate f2 = new MyClass<ValueTypeBar().Foo; // Fails - wrong return type
```

The error is generated inside of `MyClass<T>` because `T` could be a `struct`, so the complier can't guarantee that that `Foo` can be assigned a `FooDelegate`.   If you add a `class` constraint to `MyClass<T>` the code will compile.

```
public class MyClass<T> : MyBaseClass where T : class, IBar, new()
```

Comment: Silly me assumed that using an interface as generic constraint would implicitly mean 'class' too - I didn't knew you could use interfaces with value types. First issue solved, adding class was the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

There must be something else going on with your example here. I'm currently able to compile and run the following example and receive the expected result:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var x = new MyClass<Bar>();
        FooDelegate test = x.Foo;
        test("Do It");
    }
    public delegate IBar FooDelegate(string str);
    public interface IBar { }
    public class Bar : IBar { }
    public class MyClass<T> where T : IBar, new()
    {
        T item;
        public T Foo(string input) { Console.WriteLine(input); return item; }
    }
}
```

[DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/isTgI5)

Comment: You are right, I though that the problem would arise with the short version I posted, it doesn't.
Apprently there are some subtleties I'm wasn't aware of with delegate, here is an exemple of my issue on DotNetFiddle : https://dotnetfiddle.net/JncI6w

Comment: Oh, in that case the issue is attempting to apply a non-generic delegate to a generic function. If you made the delegate generic with the same constraints it should be fine, or attempted to apply to the method on an already declared instance, as I did in the code sample above.

Comment: But I can't make it generic, the base class has to deal with the interface only, and has no knowledge of its generic sub-class :(
I either need to sacrifice some part of the generic implementation to use the interface instead of T, or create a dummy function that would match the delegate signature, and that would defeat its initial purpose.

Answer (score 2):

At least in your DotNetFiddle example, you can make the first assignment to `funcA` possible by changing the generic constraint to `where T: Item, new()`.

In the second assignment, the delegate uses type T both as return type and as parameter type. I believe this leads to the sometimes strange effects of covariance and contravariance ([MSDN about Co/Contravariance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-usa/library/ms173174.aspx)): 
Let us assume that a generic instance uses a type `class SubItem : Item {...}`
for type parameter `T` of your class `TypedFactory<T>`.

It is ok to use `SubItem` as return type, since the return type will still be of (sub)type `Item`, and the delegate variable (e.g. `funcA`) still "satisfies" the contract described by the declaration of the delegate type.

But what happens if we used `SubItem` as a *parameter* type? The delegate variable (e.g. `funcB`) could no longer be called in each context which the declaration of the delegate type promises, e.g. `Item blubb; factory.funcB("I am alive too", blubb)` is not possible - the types do not match, since `blubb` is *not* of type `SubItem`. Since this might happen, the compiler has to complain here.

Maybe it is an option for you to make the delegates generic?

```
using System;

public interface IItem
{
    string id {get;set;}
}


public class Item : IItem
{
    public string id{get;set;}
}

public class BaseFactory<T>
    where T: IItem, new()
{
    public DelegateHolder.MakeWithID<T> funcA;
    public DelegateHolder.MakeWithIDAndOther<T> funcB;
}

public class TypedFactory<T> : BaseFactory<T>
    where T : IItem, new()
{

        public TypedFactory()
        {
            funcA = makeNew;
            funcB = makeNewFromOther;
        }

        public T makeNew(string itemId)
        {
            T _item = new T();
            _item.id = itemId;
            return _item;
        }

        public T makeNewFromOther(string itemId, T other)
        {
            T _item = new T();
            _item.id = itemId;
            return _item;
        }

}

public class DelegateHolder
{
    public delegate T MakeWithID<T>(string id) where T: IItem, new();
    public delegate T MakeWithIDAndOther<T>(string id, T other) where T: IItem, new();
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var x = new TypedFactory<Item>();
        BaseFactory<Item> factory = x;

        Item someItem = factory.funcA("I am alive");

        Console.WriteLine(someItem.id);
        Console.WriteLine(factory.funcB("I am alive too", someItem).id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed I could have used generic delegate, but on the base class I need to deal with the interface only, so I can't really use this trick here... :(
Very informative though -- thanks a lot !