# Why is IEnumerable(of T) not accepted as extension method receiver

Tags: c#, .net, generics, extension-methods, type-inference

Complete **question** before code:

Why is `IEnumerable<T>` `where T : ITest` not accepted as receiver of an extension method that expects `this IEnumerable<ITest>`?

And now the **code**:

I have three types:

```
public interface ITest { }
public class Element : ITest { }
public class ElementInfo : ITest { }
```

And two extension methods:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<ElementInfo> Method<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> collection) 
        where T : ITest
    {
→        return collection.ToInfoObjects();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<ElementInfo> ToInfoObjects(
        this IEnumerable<ITest> collection)
    {
        return collection.Select(item => new ElementInfo());
    }
}
```

The compiler error I get (on the marked line):

> `CS1929` : `'IEnumerable<T>'` does not contain a definition for `'ToInfoObjects'` and the best extension method overload `'Extensions.ToInfoObjects(IEnumerable<ITest>)'` requires a receiver of type `'IEnumerable<ITest>'`

Why is this so? The receiver of the `ToInfoObjects` extension method is an `IEnumerable<T>` and by the generic type constraint, `T` must implement `ITest`.

**Why is then the receiver not accepted**? My guess is the covariance of the `IEnumerable<T>` but I am not sure.

If I change `ToInfoObjects` to receive `IEnumerable<T> where T : ITest`, then everything is ok.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Consider this:

```
public struct ValueElement : ITest { }
```

and this:

```
IEnumerable<ValueElement> collection = ...
collection.Method(); //OK, ValueElement implement ITest, as required.
collection.ToInfoObjects() //Error, IEnumerable<ValueElement> is not IEnumerable<ITest>
                           //variance does not work with value types.
```

So that not every type allowed for `Method` also allowed for `ToInfoObjects`. If you add `class` constraint to `T` in `Method`, then your code will compile.

Comment: Now that you've said it, it seems obvious to me. T could have been the value type and of course it wouldn't work. Thank you very much. As a follow up, I would like to [link to the reason](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12454794/why-covariance-and-contravariance-do-not-support-value-type) why co(ntra)variance does not work with value types.

Answer (score -1):

You can do the following:

```
    public static IEnumerable<ElementInfo> Method<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> collection)
        where T : ITest
    {
        return collection.ToInfoObjects();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<ElementInfo> ToInfoObjects<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
        return collection.Select(item => new ElementInfo());
    }
```

Notice  on ToInfoObjects.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I know what I can do to solve the problem, and even more, I have written it in the original post. What I wanted is to know why the problem happens, not how to solve it.

Comment: @KornelijePetak Oh, sorry for not paying enough attention to your question.