# How to use covariance for value types?

Tags: c#, covariance

You can't use covariance for value types:

```
Func<string> refTypeFunc = () => "foo";
Func<int> valueTypeFunc = () => 123;

Func<object> a = refTypeFunc; // works
Func<object> b = valueTypeFunc; // doesn't work
```

[This answer by Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12454932/4037348) explains why:

> Basically, variance applies when the CLR can ensure that it doesn't need to make any *representational change* to the values. References all look the same - so you can use an `IEnumerable<string>` as an `IEnumerable<object>` without any change in representation; the native code itself doesn't need to know what you're doing with the values at all, so long as the infrastructure has guaranteed that it will definitely be valid.
>
> For value types, that doesn't work - to treat an `IEnumerable<int>` as an `IEnumerable<object>`, the code using the sequence would have to know whether to perform a boxing conversion or not.

Well, poop. At least for `Func` you can do this:

```
Func<object> c = () => valueTypeFunc();
```

However, such an easy way out can't be used for most cases. Say I have an interface defined as:

```
interface ICovariant<out T>
{
    Func<T> InnerFunc { get; }
}
```

Now if I have an `ICovariant<T>`, I can't cast it to `ICovariant<object>`, and I see no easy way out of it. I know `T` can be an `object` - everything can. What can I do in this case? If there's no easy workaround, what else would be the best approach?

Comment: Maybe ask yourself why your design needs you to cast generic values to `object` which is basically defeating the entire purpose of generics in the first place.

Comment: @juharr Both the implementation and usage is much cleaner when using generics. There is a method which returns `T` - returning `object` would add a lot of ugly downcasting in calling code. And using `T` as an `object` would be very useful for polymorphism, say adding many of my object instances to a list.

Comment: If you want to ensure there will be no representational changes, just stick a `where T : class` in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to make a special implementation of your covariant interface to do that conversion for you.  Something like this:

```
public class Boxer<T, U> : ICovariant<T> where U : struct, T
{
    public Boxer( ICovariant<U> foo )
    {
        mFoo = foo;
    }

    public Func<T> CallMe => () => mFoo.CallMe();

    private readonly ICovariant<U> mFoo;
}
```

This now allows you to wrap value-type implementations of the `ICovariant<T>` interface.  If you find all the generic parameters obnoxious to type, you can create a static method to do the deduction for you:

```
static void BoxIt<T, U>( IFoo<U> fooU, out IFoo<T> fooT ) where U : struct, T
{
    fooT = new Boxer<T, U>( fooU );
}
```