# Covariance and CS0266

Tags: c#, covariance

We know that co-variance allows us to do things like this:

```cs
IEnumerable<object> objects;
IEnumerable<string> strings = new[] { "hello", "world" };
objects = strings;
```

This code compiles, and works, due to co-variance.

However, if I use a bound generic, I get an error, as in the example:

```
void Test<T>(T blah) where T : ISerializable
{
    IEnumerable<T> x = new[] { blah };
    IEnumerable<ISerializable> y;
    y = x;
}
```

Gives the following error

```
[CS0266] Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializable>'. 
An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

In my head, this should work. I suspected that this could be related to some incompatibility with value types, and this was true. If I change the signature to

```cs
void Test<T>(T blah) where T : class, ISerializable
```

the code compiles with no errors.

But why? And how is this related to the error message?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12454794/why-covariance-and-contravariance-do-not-support-value-type

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36364062/how-to-use-covariance-for-value-types

Comment: And for context - https://stackoverflow.com/a/4098434/43846