# Cast an Interface and IQueryable<Interface> to its concrete implementation

Tags: c#, .net, interface, casting

I have `Class` B, C, and D inherited from Interface `IA`. Now I've got `IQueryable<B>`, `IQueryable<C>`, and `IQueryable<D>` that requires a method to do some stuff with some of the properties in `IA`.

```
public IQueryable<T> DoStuff<T>(IQueryable<IA> samples) where T: IA{
    // something that filters samples. Ommited

    return samples.Select(s => (T)s).AsQueryable(); // works
    //return (IQueryable<T>)samples; //InvalidCastException
}

var samples; // samples can be IQueryable<B>, IQueryable<C>, or IQueryable<D>
samples = DoStuff(samples);
```

**Two questions:**

1. Why didn't it cast with `IQueryable<T>`? And it did cast when looping and casting one by one.
2. Initially, B, C, and D inherited from class `A`. That didn't work because I could not cast down a class from A to B, C, D. Then I changed `A` to `IA`. However, I've read some people said that when you need to cast down an interface to its concrete implementation, you have a design problem. Do I need to avoid casting down here? If so, what's a good approach to achieve the goal?

Comment: The duplicate I suggested actually pre-dates co-variance being added in C# 4.  See [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12454794/why-covariance-and-contravariance-do-not-support-value-type) - you can resolve by adding `class` to your type constraint (i.e `where T : class, IA`).

Comment: @CharlesMager Thanks!

Comment: Something is wrong about the duplicate... this question is talking about `Base-->Derived` while the "duplicate" talks about `Derived-->Base`, more so, it should just accept an `IQueryable<T>` as parameter and not bother with any casting.