# How to check if `IEnumerable<T1>` covariant to `IEnumerable<T2>`?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, covariance

What is common rule to check if `IEnumerable<T1>` covariant to `IEnumerable<T2>` ?

I've made some experiments:

---

**1.**

```
Object Obj = "Test string";
IEnumerable<Object> Objs = new String[100];
```

*Works because `IEnumerable<out T>` is covariant and `String` inherits `Object`.*

**2.**

```
interface MyInterface{}
struct MyStruct:MyInterface{}
.....
Object V = new MyStruct();
Console.WriteLine(new MyStruct() is Object); // Output: True. 
IEnumerable<Object> Vs = new MyStruct[100]; // Compilation error here
```

*`MyStruct` is actually an `Object`, but it does not work because `Object` is reference type and `MyStruct` is value type. OK, I see some logic here.*

**3.**

```
Console.WriteLine(new MyStruct() is ValueType); // Output: "True"
ValueType V2 = new MyStruct();
IEnumerable<ValueType> Vs2 = new MyStruct[100]; // Compilation error here
```

*Should work because `IEnumerable<out T>` is covariant and `MyStruct` IS `ValueType`, but does not work... OK, maybe `MyStruct` does not actually inheritst `ValueType`....*

**4.**

```
MyInterface V3 = new MyStruct(); 
Console.WriteLine(V3 is MyInterface); // Output: "True" 
IEnumerable<MyInterface> Vs3 = new MyStruct[100]; // Compilation error here
```

*Even this way: "Cannot convert MyStruct to MyInterface". Oh, really?? You just did it one line before...*

---

I've tried to formulate common rule:

```
public static bool IsCovariantIEnumerable(Type T1, Type T2  ){          
    return (T2.IsAssignableFrom(T1)) && !T2.IsValueType; // Is this correct??
}
```

---

So, questions is how to actually determine if `IEnumerable<T1>` covariant to `IEnumerable<T2>`? Is my `IsCovariantIEnumerable(...)` function correct? If yes, is there any simplier way to check it? If not, how to fix it?

*See also these articles: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033912/c-sharp-variance-problem-assigning-listderived-as-listbase), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12454794/why-covariance-and-contravariance-do-not-support-value-type).*

Comment: Value types simply do not support co-variance; it shouldn't be suprising given that value types do not support *inheritance* at all. If you need to use a value type as an interface and/or `object`, you need to box it - e.g. `array.Cast<IMyInterface>`. It's not clear what part of this you don't understand, given that the questions you linked answer this very question as well :)

Comment: @Luaan, I just want to have complete rule to check if `IEnumerable<T1>` covariant to `IEnumerable<T2>`. I am still not sure if my `IsCovariantIEnumerable()` function is correct.

Comment: In terms of supporting interfaces, [`IsAssignableFrom`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom(v=vs.110).aspx) might do better than `IsSubclassOf`

Comment: @grek40, yes, I missed interfaces.

Comment: Please note that your example 4 is not working because `MyStruct` is a `struct`. If it is a `class` it works fine, so it is consistent with the first example.

Comment: @fknx, yes, but `MyStruct` implements `MyInterface`. That is why I've tried it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your specific case it does not work because value types do not support co-variance.

But for the question how to determine *if* an `IEnumerable<T2>` is co-variant to `IEnumerable<T1>`:

The method `Type.IsAssignableFrom()` tells you if an instance of a certain type is assignable to a variable of this type. So you can implement your method like that:

```
public static bool IsCovariantIEnumerable(Type T1, Type T2)
{
    Type enumerable1 = typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(T1);
    Type enumerable2 = typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(T2);
    return enumerable1.IsAssignableFrom(enumerable2);
}
```

Usage:

```
if (IsCovariantIEnumerable(typeof(object), typeof(string))
    Console.WriteLine("IEnumerable<string> can be assigned to IEnumerable<object>");
```

But `IsCovariantIEnumerable(typeof(object), typeof(MyStruct))` will return `false` for the reason stated above.

---

For completeness: Of course you don't need an extra method as you can easily do `typeof(IEnumerable<object>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IEnumerable<string>)`.

Comment: Actually checking the `IEnumerable<...>` type for assignability is definitely more straight forward than second guessing the item type behavior. Clean solution, I didn't think of.

Comment: @grek40 You're right, I was thinking about OP's method implementation and thereby forgot the straight call to `IsAssignableFrom`. Added it for completeness.

Comment: I see that your `IsCovariantIEnumerable` works fine. But still question is: "Is my `IsCovariantIEnumerable` also correct or not?" Are there any examples where your function works, but mine does not?

Comment: @Astronavigator as it stands now I think you're one is correct, too. (I only read your first version using `IsSubClass` before answering).

Comment: @RenéVogt, yes, I've corrected it after grek40's comment.

Answer (score 2):

Value types do not support covariance as it would change their internal representation [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12454932/6309244).

If you want to avoid weird cases i would recommend using `IsAssignableFrom` instead:

`public static bool IsCovariantIEnumerable(Type T1, Type T2) => T1.IsAssignableFrom(T2);`