# Implicit convertion of generic types parameterized with reference types vs value types

Tags: c#, generics

Why does C# implicitly convert generic types parameterized with a reference type implementing an interface to the same generic type parameterized with the implemented interface, but not perform the same implicit conversion for reference types?

Essentially, why does the first line compile but the second one fail?

```
IEnumerable<IComparable<Version>> x = Enumerable.Empty<Version>();
IEnumerable<IComparable<int>> y = Enumerable.Empty<int>();
```

Especially great would be a reference to the part of the spec that describes this behavior.

Comment: The second would require boxing.

Comment: True, but the standard says that boxing conversions are implicit, just like converting a class reference to an interface reference. (§6.1.6-7)

Comment: I'm not big on reading the spec but I'm guessing that has to do with direct convertions, where as this is a co-variant convertion.  Basically the first one is assigning a sequence of references to a sequence of references where as the second is attempting to assign a sequence of values to a sequence of references, meaning it needs to box each potential value in the sequence for that to work.

Comment: @juharr - I figured that too, but I was hoping to find a more detailed explanation of when value types are implicitly boxed and when they are not. I couldn't find it in the spec or with googling, but of course that's no guarantee its not out there.

Comment: Hopefully one of the guys on here that know the spec will be able to point you to the exact answer you're looking for.

Comment: Voting to reopen because, while the linked question certainly answers one part, none of the answers there attempt to give "the part of the spec that describes this behavior" (nor would that be appropriate there). It isn't completely trivial to see that the root cause is the same in both cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Short answer

Despite the name "implicit", implicit conversions don't apply unless the rules explicitly say they do, and the rules don't allow boxing conversions when going from `IEnumerable<int>` to `IEnumerable<IComparable<int>>`. As a simpler case, you can't go from `IEnumerable<int>` to `IEnumerable<object>` for the same reason, and that case is well documented.

## Long answer

OK, first of all, why *would* `IEnumerable<T>` convert to `IEnumerable<IComparable<T>>` at all? This is covered in §6.1.6 ([C# Language Specification 5.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029)):

> The implicit reference conversions are:
>
> [...]
>
> - From any *reference-type* to an interface or delegate type `T` if it has an implicit identity or reference conversion to an interface or
>     delegate type `T0` and
>     `T0` is variance-convertible (§13.1.3.2) to `T`.

And §13.1.3.2 says:

> A type `T<A1, …, An>` is
>   variance-convertible to a type `T<B1, …, Bn>` 
>   if `T` is either an interface or a delegate type
>   declared with the variant type parameters `T<X1, …, Xn>`, 
>   and for each variant type parameter
>   `Xi` one of the following holds:
>
> - `Xi` is covariant and an implicit reference or identity conversion exists from `Ai` to
>     `Bi`

Since `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant in `T`, this means that if there is an implicit **reference** or identity conversion from `T` to `IComparable<T>`, then there is an implicit reference conversion from `IEnumerable<T>` to `IEnumerable<IComparable<T>>`, by virtue of these being variance-convertible.

I emphasized "reference" for a reason, of course. Since `Version` implements `IComparable<Version>`, there is an implicit reference conversion:

> - From any *class-type* `S` to any *interface-type* `T`, provided `S`
>     implements `T`.

Right, so now, why doesn't `IEnumerable<int>` implicitly convert to `IEnumerable<IComparable<int>>`? After all, `int` implicitly converts to `IComparable<int>`:

```
IComparable<int> x = 0;  // sure
```

But it does so *not* through a reference conversion or an identity conversion, but through a *boxing* conversion (§6.1.7):

> A boxing conversion exists from any *non-nullable-value-type* [...] to
>   any *interface-type* implemented by the *non-nullable-value-type*.

The rules of §13.1.3.2 do not allow boxing conversions in considering whether a variance conversion is possible, and there is no other rule that would enable an implicit conversion from `IEnumerable<int>` to `IEnumerable<IComparable<int>>`. Despite the name, implicit conversions are covered by explicit rules.

There is actually a much simpler illustration of this problem:

```
object x = 0;  // sure, an int is an object
IEnumerable<object> x = new int[] { 0 };  // except when it's not
```

This isn't allowed for the same reason: there is no reference conversion from `int` to `object`, only a boxing conversion, and those are not considered. And in this form, there are several questions on Stack Overflow that explain why this is not allowed (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12454794/why-covariance-and-contravariance-do-not-support-value-type)). To summarize: it's not that this is *impossible*, but to support it, the compiler would have to generate supporting code to stick the code for the boxing conversion somewhere. The C# team valued transparency in this case over ease of use and decided to allow identity-preserving conversions only.

Finally, as a matter of practical consideration, suppose you had an `IEnumerable<int>` and you needed an `IEnumerable<IComparable<int>>`, how would you get it? Well, by doing the boxing yourself:

```
Func<int, IComparable<int>> asComparable = i => i;  // compiles to ldarg ; box ; ret
IEnumerable<IComparable<int>> x = Enumerable.Empty<int>().Select(asComparable);
```

Of course using `Enumerable.Cast` would be more practical here; I wrote it this way to highlight that an implicit conversion is involved. There is a cost to this operation, and that's just the point; the C# designers wanted this cost to be explicit.