# Cast needed for generic constraints

Tags: c#, .net, list, generics

I have created a method with two generic parameters where one parameter (`itemsToAdd`) must be the same type as the generic parameter of the next parameter (`inputList`).

See this demo code:

```
public class GenericsDemo
{
    public void AddToList<TList, TItems>(TList inputList, params TItems[] itemsToAdd)
        where TItems : IConvertible
        where TList : IEnumerable<TItems>

    {
        IEnumerable<IConvertible> someOtherList;

        // Sounds good, doesn't work..
        //someOtherList = inputList;

        // This works
        someOtherList = (IEnumerable<IConvertible>)inputList;
    }
}
```

I would expect the `inputList` can be directly assigned into the `IEnumerable<IConvertible> someOtherList`, but it needs a cast. Why the cast is needed?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance

Comment: `IList<T>` is invariant so an `IList<TItems>` is not an `IList<IConvertible>`.

Comment: I just found the `someOtherList = (IList<IConvertible>)inputList;` will throw runtime exception, even if I changed the `TList` constraint to `IEnumerable<TItems>` which is covariant

Comment: You should change your target (`IList<IConvertible>`) to `IEnumerable<IConvertible>`. Changing the source compile time type is not improving anything.

Comment: @grek40, yes, you are right, I didn't realized the `IList` is invariant.. anyway it will throw runtime exception with the `IEnumerable<IConvertible>`

Comment: sorry, it will not throw the exception, I had there one place where I did not changed it.. I will edit the question to make it clear..

Comment: Now the question is correct..

Comment: You need to add a `class` constraint to `TItems` for `someOtherList = inputList` to compile. Variance is not supported when the element type is a struct.

Comment: @chviLadislav: I'm a little confused as to whether there is actually a question here or not? Your question is "I would expect the inputList can be directly assigned into the IList<IConvertible> someOtherList, but it needs a cast. Why the cast is needed?" but you have no instances of `IList` in your question. Did you just edit the actual problem out of your question? If so the question makes no sense any more (because it isn't a question). Your question isn't *supposed* to be correct. It is supposed to show a problem and the answer shows the solution.

Comment: @Chris, I made a mistake with the `IList`, now after the edit it should be clear (`IEnumerable` is correct of course). The question is still the same - why the cast is needed? Why the compiler complains if the cast is not in place? From my point of view, it is type safe to do the commented line `someOtherList = inputList;`

Comment: @Lee, thanks, that's the answer! I need to add the class constraint..

Comment: @chviLadislav: In that case you should edit the bit I quoted to refer to `IEnumerable` rather than `IList` as well. Otherwise your question makes no sense due to not using `IList`anywhere. And also you don't need the "EDIT" section saying what you've edited - if you want to record that sort of thing then the edit page has a space for reasons - what your question used to say is not relevant to people coming to it now and just increases confusion.

Comment: @Chris, this is my first question here. the next time it will be better:) Thanks for your comments, I didn't know the edits can be seen..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Covariance only works for classes, not for structs ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12454794/87698)).

Thus, if you restrict `TItems` to reference types, your code compiles ([fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sqbt5T)):

```
    where TItems : class, IConvertible
```