# Generic method with Func parameter, Func contravariance doesn't seem to work

Tags: c#, .net, generics, variance

.NET's `Func<T1, T2, TResult>` is written so that `T1` and `T2` are contravariant and `TResult` is covariant.

This means that:

```
Func<object, object, bool> objectEquals = object.Equals;
Func<MyObject, MyObject, bool> myObjectEquals = objectEquals;
```

is a valid assignment.

Now, I have a class with methods along these lines:

```
public void DoSomething<T>(T value)
{
    DoSomethingCore(T, Object.Equals);
}

protected abstract void DoSomethingCore<T>(T value, Func<T, T, bool> equals);
```

The code would not compile, with the following error:

> CS0123 No overload for 'object.Equals(object, object)' matches delegate 'Func<T, T, bool>'

Why does contravariance not seem to work in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Contravariance, and variance in general, [don't work with value types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12454794/1313143).

Hence, you must constrain the `DoSomething` method to only work with reference types if you want to use `Object.Equals` as the function for `Func<T, T, bool>`.

In other words, add `where T : class` in the method signature:

```
public void DoSomething<T>(T value) where T : class
{
    DoSomethingCore(T, Object.Equals);
}
```