# Generic constraint ignores co-variance

Tags: c#, generics, covariance

Let's say we have an interface like

```
public interface IEnumerable<out T>
{ /*...*/ }
```

that is *co-variant* in `T`.

Then we have another interface and a class implementing it:

```
public interface ISomeInterface {}
public class SomeClass : ISomeInterface
{}
```

Now the co-variance allows us to do the following

```
IEnumerable<ISomeInterface> e = Enumerable.Empty<SomeClass>();
```

So a `IEnumerable<SomeClass>` *is assignable* to a variable (or method parameter) of type `IEnumerable<ISomeInterface>`.

But if we try this in a generic method:

```
public void GenericMethod<T>(IEnumerable<T> p) where T : ISomeInterface
{
    IEnumerable<ISomeInterface> e = p;
    // or
    TestMethod(p);
}
public void TestMethod(IEnumerable<ISomeInterface> x) {}
```

we get the **compiler error CS0266** telling us that an `IEnumerable<T>` cannot be converted to an `IEnumerable<ISomeInterface>`.

The constraint clearly states the `T` is derived from `ISomeInterface`, and since `IEnumerable<T>` is co-variant in `T`, this assignment should work (as shown above).

Is there any technical reason why this cannot work in a generic method? Or anything I missed that makes it too expensive for the compiler to figure it out?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change your `GenericMethod` and add generic constraint `class`:

```
public void GenericMethod<T>(IEnumerable<T> p) where T : class, ISomeInterface
{
    IEnumerable<ISomeInterface> e = p;
    // or
    TestMethod(p);
}
```

[Covariance does not support structs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12454794/why-covariance-and-contravariance-do-not-support-value-type), so we need to tell that we want to use classes only.

Comment: Oh, beat me to it. Now I remember I read something about that struct/variance problem some days ago. thank you for the quick response.

Comment: @RenéVogt glad to help