# Are constraints ignored when checking co/contra-variance?

Tags: c#, covariance, contravariance

I see no other explanation when looking at such code:

```
public interface IParam
{

}
public class Param : IParam
{

}
public interface ITest<out T> where T : IParam
{

}
 public class Test : ITest<Param>
{

}

public class Tester
{
    public void Run<O>(ITest<O> a)
        where O : IParam
    {
        Get(a); // ERROR
        ITest<Param> b = new Test();
        Get(b); // OK
    }
    public void Get(ITest<IParam> input)
    {

    }
}
```

Despite both types `a` in `b` are declared effectively with type parameter derived from `IParam` only the second passes compilation.

Yet so far I didn't find a notice saying constraints are ignored when dealing with covariance/contravariance. Am I missing something or indeed it is the case (constraints are ignored)?

Comment: What is the exact compiler error message? At first glance I'd say the `IParam` constraint does not constrain it to be a `class`, it could be a `struct`, but [variance is only supported for **reference** types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46451029/generic-constraint-ignores-co-variance) (hence it works with the _class_ `Param`)

Comment: @RenéVogt `cannot convert from 'ITest<O>' to 'ITest<IParam>'`

Comment: I think @RenéVogt is correct: When I add `class` to both constraints, it compiles. It's not the most informative error message I've ever seen.

Comment: @EdPlunkett It's sufficient to add it to the constraints of `Run<O>`.

Comment: @RenéVogt Derp. Yes, of course.