# Storing/casting Parameter<T> as Parameter<object> including Parameter<int>?

Tags: c#, object, generics

I need to store the `Parameter<T1>` returned by `Build()` as a `Parameter<object>` (because I'm storing the parameters in an array, the other way is just wayyyy too much copy-pasting the same class for each amount of parameters, since c# doesn't have variadic generics).

The problem is the cast `(Parameter<object>) (object) (/* value of type Parameter<int> */);`, since `int` isn't castable to `object`. How do I solve this issue?

I have the following monstrosity (imagine `T1` is `int`):

```
    public static IEventBuilder<(IOrigin origin, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)>
        Params<T1, T2>(
            this IEventBuilder<(IOrigin origin, string msg)> eventBuilder,
            Func<IParameterBuilder<string>, IParameterBuilder<T1>> param1,
            Func<IParameterBuilder<string>, IParameterBuilder<T2>> param2)
    {
        return new ParamsBuilder<(IOrigin, T1, T2)>(
            eventBuilder,
            (origin, objs) => (origin, (T1) objs[0], (T2) objs[1]), // ignore this line
            (Parameter<object>) (object) param1(new RootParameterBuilder()).Build(),  // Build() returns Parameter<T1> (e.g. int)
            (Parameter<object>) (object) param2(new RootParameterBuilder()).Build());
    }
```

Not really important, but in case you need a bit of context, here's some example usage of `Params`:

```
        _dispatcher.On // IEventBuilder<IEvent>
            .Chat() // IEventBuilder<(IOrigin, string)>
            .Params( // IEventBuilder<(IOrigin, double)>
                p => p // IParameterBuilder<string>
                    .Transform(Convert.ToInt32) // IParameterBuilder<int>
                    .Transform(i => i + 128.0)) // IParameterBuilder<double>
            .Invoke(t =>
            {
                // t is (IOrigin, double)
            });
```

Comment: Can you show Parameter class code?

Comment: @Evk https://pastebin.com/mMQtvTc0

Comment: Well you are out of luck here it seems. And how exactly you use those `Parameter<object>`? Can't use store them as `object`s?

Comment: @Evk I need to call `Parameter<T>.ParseFunc(string) : T`. I could do with it returning an object, that is fine. But I store the parsed results in an object[], and then later pass that on to the function marked with `// ignore this line` to give it the proper types back. I know it's a dirty workaround, but I haven't figured out a different way (apart from copy-pasting the 60loc ParamsBuilder class for every amount of parameters.. https://pastebin.com/gibEsJLd And I wouldn't be able to use a loop and argasdhsdf)

Comment: If nothing else helps, you can create parent 'Parameter' class, add ParseFuncUntyped<string, object> function there and then store your parameters as 'Parameter' objects. You can assign that function in 'Parameter<T>' constructor as ParseFuncUntyped = (s) => ParseFunc(s); Hope you got the idea

Comment: @Evk That worked! Do you want to make a quick reply to it so I can accept it as a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If nothing else helps - create `Parameter` class, move (and adjust) all shared functionality there and inherit `Parameter<T>` from it. In this case you can move `Optional` flag and adjust ParseFunc:

```
public Func<string, object> ParseFuncUntyped {get; protected set;}
```

Then assign that function in constructor of `Parameter<T>` and store your parameters as `Parameter`

Answer (score 0):

To store a `Parameter<int>` in a `Parameter<object>` is not possible. That said, if you make an interface `IParameter<T>` and make it [covariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance) (`IParameter<out T>`) you could indeed store an `IParameter<int>` in an `IParameter<object>`.

Comment: That's not true actually, because `int` is a struct and covariance does not work for structs.

Comment: @Evk huh, interesting, I guess I need to do more lowlevel work... never realized that. Will think about the OPs problem some more...

Comment: You might be interested to read this answer and link in it which explains why it works like that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12454932/5311735 then.