# Covariance and Contravariance in Generics

Tags: c#, generics, covariance, contravariance

I have next code:

```
public interface IOrder
{
}

public interface IManagedOrder<out T> where T : IOrder
{
    T Order { get; }
}

public class ManagedPrivateExchange
{
    public void PlaceOrder(IManagedOrder<IOrder> mOrder)
    {
    }
}

public class ManagedOrder<T> : IManagedOrder<T> where T : IOrder
{  
    public T Order {  get; }
    public ManagedPrivateExchange Exchange { get; set; }
    public void Place()
    {
        Exchange.PlaceOrder(this)//<-----here is ERROR #1 
    }
}
```

Error details:

> CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'ManagedOrder' to 'IManagedOrder'    Trading.Core

**QUESTION:**

- Is it possible to assign this `ManagedOrder<T>` (where T is IOrder) to `IManagedOrder<IOrder>`. What I need to change to achieve my goal?

Comment: change constraints to `where T : IOrder, class`. [Value-types don't support variance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12454794/why-covariance-and-contravariance-do-not-support-value-type).

Comment: awesome, so easy, but I never saw this information before