# Why can't I cast int[] as IEnumerable<object>?

Tags: c#, casting, covariance

In C# I'm getting some strange results when casting an `object` variable (which happens to hold an integer array) as an `IEnumerable<object>`.

```
object arr = new[] {1, 2, 3};
var tst1 = arr as IEnumerable<int>;
var tst2 = arr as IEnumerable<object>;
```

When this runs, the first cast succeeds, but the second fails. However, if I debug this code in Visual Studio and evaluate `arr as IEnumerable<object>` in the Immediate Window or Watch panes, the cast succeeds. So I have a few questions:

1) Why is the cast invalid?

2) Why is the debugger able to perform the cast?

Bonus Points:

-Does `T[]` really implement `IEnumerable<T>`? Is an `int` really an `object`?

-When casting to a type with a covariant generic argument, what types are valid for the instance?

Comment: The cast is invalid because [variance for value types is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12454794/why-covariance-and-contravariance-do-not-support-value-type). The debugger can do it, because it's buggy. (let me search the link, there already was a question about that...)

Comment: To answer your bonus questions: (1) The spec says that `T[]` is *implicitly convertible* to `IEnumerable<T>`.  I don't know what "really implement" means; can you give an example of "really implement" vs "fakely implement"?  (2) `int` is a *derived type* of `ValueType`, which is a derived type of `Object`. Again, you're using "really" in a way I don't understand. (3) The question is underspecified; is the cast an explicit conversion or merely an implicit conversion?  The rules for casts are *complicated*. Consult the spec, or ask a more specific question.

Comment: If the last question is really "what are the rules for an implicit reference conversion from `I<A>` to `I<B>` where `I<T>` is an interface or delegate covariant in T, that's straightforward. There are only two possibilities: either `A` has an *identity conversion* to `B`, or `A` has an *implicit reference conversion* to `B`. But again: **read the specification**. It is published for your convenience.