# Using subtypes of a generic type, resolving error CS1503 cannot convert

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I'm having difficulties understanding how to use subtypes of a generic type.

Suppose the following situation

```
public abstract class A { }
public class B : A { }
public abstract class WrapperA<T>  where T :A { }
public class WrapperB : WrapperA<B> { }
```

I have a generic class `WrapperA<T>` that has been contstrain to only have class `A` or cubtypes of class `A` as generic type `T`

I also have a class `UserA` that requires a `WrapperA` element in it's  constructor.

```
public abstract class UserA
{
    protected UserA(WrapperA input) { }
}
```

I tried the above, but that won't fly. This gives me the error:

**`Error    CS0305  Using the generic type 'WrapperA<T>' requires 1 type arguments`**

I actually don't care which specific `WrapperA` object I get here, but I can set it to the parentclass A as I'm sure that the generic parameter will either be `A`, or a subtype of `A`, so we adjust as follows

```
public abstract class UserA
{
    protected UserA(WrapperA<A> input) { }
}
```

Fine, no more errors so far.
But now I want to make a subclass of `UserA` , `UserB` that needs a 'WrapperB' as input.

```
public class UserB : UserA
{
    protected UserB(WrapperB input) : base(input) { }
}
```

Now this gives me the error:

**`Error    CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'WrapperB' to 'WrapperA<A>'`**

Why can't it convert `WrapperB` to `WrapperA<A>` I would think that should be possible, since `WrapperB` is a subtype of `WrapperA` and the type parameter `B` is a subtype of `A` (which it must be because of the constraint)

Is my reasoning flawed, or is this just a limitation of the compiler?

If found a workaround by defining an interface public interface `IWrapperA` and letting my `IWrapperA` implement this interface. Now i can use the IWrapperA as a parameter in my constructor, but this feels like a hacky workaround that I shoudn't need

```
public interface IWrapperA { }

public abstract class WrapperA<T> : IWrapperA where T :A { }

public abstract class UserA
{
    protected UserA(IWrapperA input) { }
}
public class UserB : UserA
{
    protected UserB(WrapperB input) : base(input) { }
}
```

What would be a better, more elegant way to solve this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Covariance error in generically constrained class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50935140/covariance-error-in-generically-constrained-class)

Comment: @shingo According to (the last sentence of) this answer it should work as I would expect it if a class constraint was used (which I did. Even stronger I constrained to classes of type `A`)

Comment: Let's say I have an `Fruit` class and I define classes `Apple` and `Banana` that inherit from `Fruit`. Now if I define a class `BowlOfApples : List<Apple>` I cannot cast an instance of `BowlOfApples` to `List<Fruit>` as it would allow be to add a `Banana` to a `BowlOfApples`. That's what you're doing here.

Comment: Try with [class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) constraint.

Comment: He meant `where T : class`, and the question is about interface, classes cannot be covariant at this moment.

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria I already have a class constraint by contraining to type `A`

Comment: @Enigmativity yes, thank you that explains it in terms I can understand :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of @Enigmativity I understand why I'm not allowed to cast an object of type `WrapperB` to type `WrapperA<A>`

This can be explained using Fruit.

Suppose the following classes

```
public abstract class Fruit { }
public class Apple : Fruit  { }
public class Banana : Fruit  { }
public class BowlOfApples : List<Apple> {}
```

The `WrapperB` class is similar to a `BowlOfApples` whereas the `WrapperA<A>` class is similar to `List<Fruit>`.

Now if I would be allowed to convert object of type `BowlOfApples` to `List<Fruit>`, I could potentially add `Banana`s to my `BowlOfApples`

```
var myBowlOfApples = new BowlOfApples();
var myBanana = new Banana();
((List<Fruit>)myBowlOfApples).Add(myBanana);
```

Which would defeat the whole purpose of defining my `BowlOfApples` as a `List<Apple>`. I would no longer be certain my `BowlOfApples` only contained `Apples`