# How do I properly work with calling methods on related but different classes in C#

Tags: c#, oop, generics, static-typing

To be honest I wasn't sure how to word this question so forgive me if the actual question isn't what you were expecting based on the title. C# is the first statically typed language I've ever programmed in and that aspect of it has been an absolute headache for me so far. I'm fairly sure I just don't have a good handle on the core ideas surrounding how to design a system in a statically typed manner.

Here's a rough idea of what I'm trying to do. Suppose I have a hierarchy of classes like so:

```
abstract class DataMold<T>
{
    public abstract T Result { get; }
}

class TextMold : DataMold<string>
{
  public string Result => "ABC";
}  

class NumberMold : DataMold<int>
{
   public int Result => 123
}
```

Now suppose I want to make a list of item where the items can be any kind of mold and I can get the `Result` property of each item in a `foreach` loop like so:

```
List<DataMold<T>> molds = new List<DataMold<T>>();
molds.Add(new TextMold());
molds.Add(new NumberMold());

foreach (DataMold<T> mold in molds)
    Console.WriteLine(mold.Result);
```

As you probably already know, that doesn't work. From what I've read in my searches, it has to do with the fact that I can't declare the List to be of type `DataMold<T>`. What is the correct way to go about something like this?

Comment: `interface IDataMold<T>` would work as  a List<IDataMold<T>>`, if an interface suites your needs.

Comment: normally this would look like `class TextMold : DataMold<string>
{
  public string Result { get; set; }
}` OR it would just have a getter:
`class TextMold : DataMold<string>
{
  public string Result { get;  private set; }
}`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The short answer: You can't.

One of the things that is counterintuitive about generic types is that they are not related. A `List<int>`, for example, has no relationship whatsoever to a `List<string>`. They do not inherit from each other, and you can't cast one to the other.

You *can* declare a [covariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/) relationship, which looks a lot like an inheritance relationship, but not between an `int` and a `string` as you have declared, since one is a value type and one is a reference type.

Your only alternative is to add another interface that they have in common, like this:

```
interface IDataMold
{
}

abstract class DataMold<T> : IDataMold
{
    public abstract T Result { get; }
}
```

Now you can store all of your molds in a `List<IDataMold>`. However, the interface has no properties, so you'd have a heckuva time getting anything out of it. You could add some properties, but they would not be type-specific, as `IDataMold` has no generic type parameter. But you could add a common property

```
interface IDataMold
{
    string ResultString { get; }
}
```

...and implement it:

```
abstract class DataMold<T>
{
    public abstract T Result { get; }
    public string ResultString => Result.ToString();
}
```

But if your only need is to display a string equivalent for each item, you can just override ToString() instead:

```
class TextMold : DataMold<string>
{
    public string Result => "ABC";
    public override string ToString() => Result.ToString();
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
List<IDataMold> molds = new List<IDataMold>();
molds.Add(new TextMold());
molds.Add(new NumberMold());

foreach (var mold in molds)
{
    Console.WriteLine(mold.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for [*covariance*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/). See the `out` keyword before `T` generic type parameter:

```
// Covariance and contravariance are only possible for
// interface and delegate generic params
public interface IDataMold<out T> 
{
   T Result { get; }
}

abstract class DataMold<T> : IDataMold<T>
{
  public abstract T Result { get; }
}

class StringMold : DataMold<string> {}

class Whatever {}

class WhateverMold : DataMold<Whatever> {}
```

Now inherit `DataMold<T>` and create a `List<IDataMold<object>>`:

```
var molds = new List<IDataMold<object>>();
molds.Add(new StringMold());
molds.Add(new WhateverMold());
```

BTW, you can't use *covariance* when it comes to cast `IDataMold<int>` to `IDataMold<object>`. Instead of repeating what's been already explained, please see this other Q&A: [Why covariance and contravariance do not support value type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12454794/why-covariance-and-contravariance-do-not-support-value-type)

If you're really forced to implement `IDataMold<int>`, that list may be of type `object`:

```
var molds = new List<object>();
molds.add(new TextMold());
molds.add(new NumberMold());
```

And you may use `Enumerable.OfType<T>` to get subsets of `molds`:

```
var numberMolds = molds.OfType<IDataMold<int>>();
var textMolds = molds.OfType<IDataMold<string>>();
```

Also, you may create two lists:

```
var numberMolds = new List<IDataMold<int>>();
var textMolds = new List<IDataMold<string>>();
```

So you might mix them later as an `IEnumerable<object>` if you need to:

```
var allMolds = numberMolds.Cast<object>().Union(textMolds.Cast<object>());
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a visitor pattern:

Add a visitor interface that accepts all your types, and implement a visitor that performs the action you want to apply to all DataMolds:

```
interface IDataMoldVisitor
{  void visit(DataMold<string> dataMold);
   void visit(DataMold<int> dataMold);
}

// Console.WriteLine for all
class DataMoldConsoleWriter : IDataMoldVisitor
{  public void visit(DataMold<string> dataMold)
   {  Console.WriteLine(dataMold.Result);
   }
   public void visit(DataMold<int> dataMold)
   {  Console.WriteLine(dataMold.Result);
   }
}
```

Add an acceptor interface that your list can hold and have your DataMold classes implement it:

```
interface IDataMoldAcceptor
{  void accept(IDataMoldVisitor visitor);
}

abstract class DataMold<T> : IDataMoldAcceptor
{  public abstract T Result { get; }
   public abstract void accept(IDataMoldVisitor visitor);
}

class TextMold : DataMold<string>
{  public string Result => "ABC";
   public override void accept(IDataMoldVisitor visitor)
   {  visitor.visit(this);
   }
}  

class NumberMold : DataMold<int>
{  public int Result => 123;
   public override void accept(IDataMoldVisitor visitor)
   {  visitor.visit(this);
   }
}
```

And finally, execute it with:

```
// List now holds acceptors
List<IDataMoldAcceptor> molds = new List<IDataMoldAcceptor>();
molds.Add(new TextMold());
molds.Add(new NumberMold());

// Construct the action you want to perform
DataMoldConsoleWriter consoleWriter = new DataMoldConsoleWriter();
// ..and execute for each mold
foreach (IDataMoldAcceptor mold in molds)
    mold.accept(consoleWriter);
```

Output is:

```
ABC
123
```

Answer (score 1):

#### `dynamic`

This can be done with the `dynamic` keyword, at the cost of performance and type safety.

```
var molds = new List<object>();     // System.Object is the most derived common base type.
molds.Add(new TextMold());
molds.Add(new NumberMold());

foreach (dynamic mold in molds)
    Console.WriteLine(mold.Result);
```

Now that `mold` is `dynamic`, C#'ll check what `mold`'s type is at run-time and then figure out what `.Result` means from there.