# Why No Implicit Conversion Allowed In This Generic Code?

Tags: c#

In the implementation of GetEnumerator() below, the compiler refuses to convert `List<T>.Enumerator` to `IEnumerator<Shape>` even though T is constrained by Shape.  (1) Why is this, and (2) is there a workaround I'm overlooking?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

interface Shape {
    void Draw();
}

class Picture<T> : IEnumerable<Shape> where T : Shape {  
List<T> shapes;
    public IEnumerator<Shape> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return shapes.GetEnumerator(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: This ought to be working, as `IEnumerator<T>` is declared covariant.  See `<out T>` in the documentation, here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerator-1?view=net-5.0

Comment: I would have thought so, too.  I'm stuck with VS 2015; perhaps the language/library variant I'm using (C# v 6, I believe) isn't up to the task?

Answer (score 6):

Change the constraint from

```
where T : Shape
```

to

```
where T : class, Shape
```

Interface covariance doesn't work for value types.

Documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance):

> Variance applies only to reference types; if you specify a value type for a variant type parameter, that type parameter is invariant for the resulting constructed type.

Comment: That did the trick.  It never occurred to me that one might implement an interface with a struct.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Because [variance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/) does not work for [value types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12454932/2501279). So if it is suitable for you can constrain `T` to be a class:

```
private class Picture<T> : IEnumerable<Shape> where T : class, Shape
{
    private List<T> shapes;
    public IEnumerator<Shape> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return shapes.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler simply does not support this kind of type inference. If your types can be reference types, [Ben's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68186159/64348) is the way to go. If not you're stuck with workarounds.

There are a few workarounds. Choose the one that makes sense for you.

1. Use [Enumerable.Cast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.cast?view=net-5.0).

```
public IEnumerator<Shape> GetEnumerator()
{
    return shapes.Cast<Shape>().GetEnumerator(); 
}
```

2. Make the list a list of `Shape`. Drawback is that your implementation will have to cast back to `T` at some point. Here's an example with some methods I've added.

```
List<Shape> shapes = new List<Shape>();
public IEnumerator<Shape> GetEnumerator()
{
    return shapes.GetEnumerator(); 
}

public void AddShape(T shape) => shapes.Add(shape);

public T GetShape() => (T)shapes.First();
```

Comment: There's also `.AsEnumerable().GetEnumerator()` if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Since List<T>.Enumerator is derived from IEnumerator<T> and the compiler knows T will be Shape or derived from Shape, it seems like a no-brainer for the compiler since implicit conversions from IEnumerator<Derived> to IEnumerator<Base> are supported by the language.  Color me surprised, but thanks for your reply!